# Please explain the purpose of Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I thought I understood what `Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries` was doing, but now i'm confused.

I pushed an update to a `MacOS` app to the App Store and a user said it was crashing for him on `macOS High Sierra`. After a very quick investigation, it seems the swift libraries were missing and one of my frameworks was written in swift (Main app was `ObjC`). I switched `Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries` to `YES`, re-uploaded a new build and everything was great with the world.

I have now uploaded a brand new `iOS` app to `Testflight` that is build for `iOS 9.3+` and remembered about this issue so thought i'd test it out.
The `Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries` setting is set to `NO` which must have been the `Xcode` default. I downloaded the app through `TestFlight` on an `iOS 9.3.2` device expecting it to crash on launch, but no, the app works perfectly fine.

How can a `macOS` app crash running on 1 major version behind of `macOS` but an `iOS` app can run perfectly fine on `iOS` that's 4 major versions behind?

Am I completely misunderstanding what this setting does?

When should we use `Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries`?

----- EDIT
I've just checked the `.app` contents and it seems it does have the swift libraries in it, which would explain why t didn't crash on `iOS 9.3.2`. So an additional question. Why would the swift libraries be there when `Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries` is set to `NO`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had to read the [documentation](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/11.4/#/itcaec37c2a6) several times, to get a clue what's going on:

> **Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries (ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES)**
>
> Always embed the Swift standard libraries in the target's products, even if the target does not contain any Swift code.

This means

- if you set `ALWAYS`... to `YES`, the libraries will definitely be embedded.
- if you set it to `NO`, they will not *always* be embedded - they might or might not be embedded, regarding of how clever the build system is able to decide that it needs them or nor (depending on the target version or so).

This is a common misinterpretation: The negation of *always* is **not** *never*, it is just *not always* (e.g. *sometimes* or so).

Comment: So if building an app with swift code or swift libraries, you might as well always have it set to YES?

Comment: No, if you use swift code, the build system will know that it needs the libraries (depending on the target iOS), so if you set it to NO, it should also work. See the doc: _This setting only applies to wrapped products, not to standalone binary products._

Comment: But it would be the same result? If you know you need them, might as well say YES. Is there a list anywhere of which iOS/MacOS versions no longer need the swift libraries bundled?

Comment: Regarding to https://swift.org/blog/abi-stability-and-apple/ it seems that since Swift 5 (and maybe macOS 10.14.4, iOS 12.2, tvOS 12.2, watchOS 5.2) the standard libraries will be included in the operating system, hence you won't need them any more.

Comment: Small pedantic nitpick when you said "opposite of always": instead of the word "opposite", the word "negation" should be used. The opposite of always actually is "never". The negation of always is "not always". :D